# Python: Update the dict[key] values list only with values not already in list

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to add/append `test_dict2` to `test_dict`, according to the below rules:

1. If the `test_dict2` dictionary key already exists in `test_dict`, update `test_dict[key]` with only new values from `test_dict2[key]`
2. If the dictionary key does not already exist in `test_dict`, add the key and value.

Example:

```
test_dict = {'s': [1, 2], 't': 2}
test_dict2 = {'s': [1, 2, 3, 'yoyoyo'], 't': 2, 'u': [3, 4]}
```

After my intended update, test_dict should look like this:

```
test_dict = {'s': [1, 2, 3, 'yoyoyo'], 't': [2], 'u': [3, 4]}
```

I have working code, but it seems so inefficient:

```
def convert_values_to_list(value):
  if isinstance(value, list) == False:
    value = [value]
  return value

for key, values in test_dict2.items():
  values = convert_values_to_list(values)
  print(key)
  print(values)
  if key not in test_dict:
    test_dict[key] = values
  else:
    test_dict[key] = convert_values_to_list(test_dict[key])
    for value in values:
      if value not in test_dict[key]:
        test_dict[key].append(value)
```

Comment: No, that will replace the values with `test_dict2` if the key already exists. I need it to append only the unique values in `test_dict2[key]` if the key already exists in `test_dict[key]`.

Comment: My bad I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
def unpack_values(data):
    for datum in data:
        if isinstance(datum, list):
            for x in datum:
                yield x
        else:
            yield datum

all_keys=set(test_dict.keys())
all_keys.update(test_dict2.keys())

for key in all_keys:
    values=[test_dict.get(key,[]), test_dict2.get(key,[])]
    test_dict[key]=list(set(unpack_values(values)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In `unpack_values(data)`, why are you using `yield` instead of `return`

Comment: It doesn't return unique values.  That's why it gets passed to the `set` constructor.

Comment: A function which uses `yield` is what's called a generator function.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD05uGo_sVI&t=44s is a good tutorial on them.

Comment: I changed my question late there… sorry. So what exactly is `unpack_values` doing?

Comment: It allows you to iterate over the values in the dictionaries.  If the values are lists, then it iterates over each item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a library to help with this, I found `deepmerge`, which also supports custom strategies, so you could make this a one-liner in theory:

```
>>> from deepmerge import always_merger
>>> a = {'s': [1, 2], 't': 2}
>>> b = {'s': [1, 2, 3, 'yoyoyo'], 't': 2, 'u': [3, 4]}
```

and then

```
>>> always_merger.merge(a, b)  # a was modified in place
{'s': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 'yoyoyo'], 't': 2, 'u': [3, 4]}

>>> {k: list(set(v)) if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for k, v in a.iteritems()}
{'s': [1, 2, 3, 'yoyoyo'], 't': [2], 'u': [3, 4]}
```